# Get sudo to ask for password via GUI

Tags: swift, bash, macos, applescript, sudo

I am running the following command in my terminal.

/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/path/to/myscript args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'

The problem is that the GUI is opened for asking password but it says **osascript** want to make changes. I want to change the word osascript to my own word.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog that is asking for your password is part of the `osascript` tool and it does not seem likely that you will be able to change it.  You would have to write your own GUI application to prompt for the password and run the command with elevated permissions.

Comment: I have GUI but I want to ask username and password. What command I should use instead of the above command?

Comment: It's a very complex topic.  I recommend https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html

Comment: ok thank you. I have read the whole document but still I couldn't accomplish

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of this?

```
let command = "do shell script \"/path/to/myscript args 2>&1 etc\" with administrator privileges"
let script = NSAppleScript(source: command)

let output = script?.executeAndReturnError(nil)

print(output)
```

This will run the command and show a GUI prompt with the name of your current Application (I'm using this in a Cocoa app). The only drawback to this as opposed to using the Process class is that you don't get any information about the command's success, you just get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expect command to handle various input issues.